# spark pass data from one map function to another

Tags: apache-spark

I have a 2 steps in my spark workflow

1st function takes a RDD and spits the squares of the numbers.

Input :- [1,2,3,4,5]

1st step Ouput:- [1,4,9,16,25]

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5],2) 
rdd = rdd.map(square_func)  # call the image_chunk_func
```

def square_func(x):
    return x*x

My second step should basically take the output of step 1 and find the cuberoot.

How can I collect the output from step 1 and pass it to step 2.

Should I rdd.collect and spit into step 2?

Python function to do multiple map functions.

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> result = rdd.map(sqr).map(cubex)
>>> rdd.collect()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another transformation to the existing computation graph:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))

scala> val cbrtRdd = rdd.map(square).map(math.cbrt)
```

Till this point, no operation takes place. You only declare what you want to be done should you execute an *action*.

`collect` and `save` are example of actions. They execute the specified operations and collect results in the driver memory or write them out to the disk respectively.

```
scala> cbrtRdd.collect
res8: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 1.5874010519681996, 2.080083823051904)
```

You may find it useful to read about transformations and actions in Spark.

*(I've used scala for these operations, but the concepts hold)*

Comment: I accept your answer but a general question  ....can I separate the functions like this ie:- rdd.map(square) --> collect the input -->rdd.parallelize([output from first function],4)--> rdd.map(math.cbrt)...ie; multiple parallelize..

Comment: @user1050619 Yes you can. A more scaleable way to do it would be: input -> square -> write square output to disk -> read square output from disk -> cube root -> write square output to disk. I'm assuming that your dataset is big enough to worry about whether the pipeline will scale (if it's not, you may be better off not using Spark).